# Virtualize Windows on Ubuntu server no GUI

Tags: 12.04, virtualization

I've been administering a remote Ubuntu 12.04 server for some time and loving it. Sadly some of the applications I would like to run hate WINE and pretty much require a Windows installation.

I don't have a GUI since I'm remote and do everything via SSH. I would like to know the easiest way to setup a Windows virtual machine and get it accessible via remote desktop.

I have a spare Windows 7 key sitting around, have some experience with X11 (did it locally and was a bit of a hassle).
Disclosure: I have 0 experience with remote virtualization.

Comment: You should check  https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/virtualization.html

Comment: You could use `VBoxHeadless` or another virtualisation solution.